# How to generate the package.json with the neccessary modules used by my application?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js using the necessary node modules.
I want to upload my application to the server with the required modules.
How to generate the package.json that uses all the modules used by my application

Comment: For future reference - do this up front! Create an package.json when you start your project using `npm init`, and then install your packages with `npm install pkgname --save`.

Comment: Yep. I guessed it right

Comment: Well... people have already suggested the necessary thingy. Here is what you can do in current scenario, write a code which will take in account all the folders in node modules and then generate dependencies for you.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite: Tricky part there is that newer versions of NPM use a flat folder structure, so all your dependencies' dependencies will be in `node_modules` too.

Comment: Never faced that issue as of now. Can't we just install it in root node_modules (dependency for specific modules) @JoeClay

Answer (score 0):

In the project root directory you have to initialize npm by running:

`npm init`

The `package.json` file will be generated and by installing the packages you need with:

`npm install --save module_name`

`--save` add the package to the dependencies.

If you want to install packages only for development purporse (testing api for example) you can install these by:

`--save-dev` add the package to the dev-dependencies.

Comment: how is this an answer at all :l